# OpenCV Libraries in CPP (Specifically, file letter_recog.cpp)

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu-16.04, geany

I am just trying to compile/build/run a sample code from the opencv libraries for cpp, and I am having an issue when I try to **build** it.

I have installed opencv correctly as per http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_gcc_cmake/linux_gcc_cmake.html
as well as moving the opencv include files from the framework file into the include for /usr/local/include/opencv2
Moving the opencv include files from the framework into that folder helped most of my problems (the opencv2 files not being found), but the problem of building the file **letter_recog.cpp** is not working. By not working, I mean that it is having a lot of build errors.

The code for the file is as follows:
https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/letter_recog.cpp

The Build errors are as follows:

```
g++ -g -std=c++14 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -lpthread  -o "letter_recog"  "letter_recog.cpp" (in directory: /home/courtneymaroney/opencv/samples/cpp)
/tmp/ccUbgW02.o: In function `read_num_class_data(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int, cv::Mat*, cv::Mat*)':
/home/courtneymaroney/opencv/samples/cpp/letter_recog.cpp:74: undefined reference to `cv::Mat::push_back(cv::Mat const&)'
/home/courtneymaroney/opencv/samples/cpp/letter_recog.cpp:77: undefined reference to `cv::Mat::copyTo(cv::_OutputArray const&) const'
/tmp/ccUbgW02.o: In function `prepare_train_data(cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat const&, int)':
/home/courtneymaroney/opencv/samples/cpp/letter_recog.cpp:100: undefined reference to `cv::Mat::zeros(int, int, int)'
/tmp/ccUbgW02.o: In function `prepare_train_data(cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat const&, int)':
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:1110: undefined reference to `cv::noArray()'
/tmp/ccUbgW02.o: In function `prepare_train_data(cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat const&, int)':
/home/courtneymaroney/opencv/samples/cpp/letter_recog.cpp:102: undefined reference to `cv::Mat::setTo(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
/tmp/ccUbgW02.o: In function `prepare_train_data(cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat const&, int)':
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:1110: undefined reference to `cv::noArray()'
/tmp/ccUbgW02.o: In function `prepare_train_data(cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat const&, int)':
/home/courtneymaroney/opencv/samples/cpp/letter_recog.cpp:106: undefined reference to `cv::Mat::setTo(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
/home/courtneymaroney/opencv/samples/cpp/letter_recog.cpp:110: undefined reference to `cv::noArray()'
/home/courtneymaroney/opencv/samples/cpp/letter_recog.cpp:110: undefined reference to `cv::noArray()'
/home/courtneymaroney/opencv/samples/cpp/letter_recog.cpp:110: undefined reference to `cv::ml::TrainData::create(cv::_InputArray const&, int, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
/tmp/ccUbgW02.o: In function `test_and_save_classifier(cv::Ptr<cv::ml::StatModel> const&, cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat const&, int, int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
/usr/local/include/opencv2/ml.hpp:349: undefined reference to `cv::noArray()'
/tmp/ccUbgW02.o: In function `build_rtrees_classifier(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
/home/courtneymaroney/opencv/samples/cpp/letter_recog.cpp:187: undefined reference to `cv::ml::RTrees::create()'
/home/courtneymaroney/opencv/samples/cpp/letter_recog.cpp:208: undefined reference to `cv::sum(cv::_InputArray const&)'
/tmp/ccUbgW02.o: In function `build_boost_classifier(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp:1110: undefined reference to `cv::noArray()'
/tmp/ccUbgW02.o: In function `build_boost_classifier(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
/home/courtneymaroney/opencv/samples/cpp/letter_recog.cpp:277: undefined reference to `cv::Mat::setTo(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
/home/courtneymaroney/opencv/samples/cpp/letter_recog.cpp:281: undefined reference to `cv::noArray()'
/home/courtneymaroney/opencv/samples/cpp/letter_recog.cpp:281: undefined reference to `cv::noArray()'
/home/courtneymaroney/opencv/samples/cpp/letter_recog.cpp:281: undefined reference to `cv::noArray()'
/home/courtneymaroney/opencv/samples/cpp/letter_recog.cpp:281: undefined reference to `cv::ml::TrainData::create(cv::_InputArray const&, int, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
/home/courtneymaroney/opencv/samples/cpp/letter_recog.cpp:287: undefined reference to `cv::ml::Boost::create()'
/home/courtneymaroney/opencv/samples/cpp/letter_recog.cpp:314: undefined reference to `cv::noArray()'
/tmp/ccUbgW02.o: In function `build_mlp_classifier(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
/home/courtneymaroney/opencv/samples/cpp/letter_recog.cpp:383: undefined reference to `cv::Mat::zeros(int, int, int)'
/tmp/ccUbgW02.o: In function `build_mlp_classifier(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
/usr/local/include/opencv2/ml.hpp:285: undefined reference to `cv::noArray()'
/usr/local/include/opencv2/ml.hpp:285: undefined reference to `cv::noArray()'
/usr/local/include/opencv2/ml.hpp:284: undefined reference to `cv::noArray()'
/usr/local/include/opencv2/ml.hpp:284: undefined reference to `cv::noArray()'
/tmp/ccUbgW02.o: In function `build_mlp_classifier(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
/home/courtneymaroney/opencv/samples/cpp/letter_recog.cpp:408: undefined reference to `cv::ml::TrainData::create(cv::_InputArray const&, int, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
/home/courtneymaroney/opencv/samples/cpp/letter_recog.cpp:411: undefined reference to `cv::ml::ANN_MLP::create()'
/tmp/ccUbgW02.o: In function `build_knearest_classifier(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int)':
/home/courtneymaroney/opencv/samples/cpp/letter_recog.cpp:440: undefined reference to `cv::ml::KNearest::create()'
/tmp/ccUbgW02.o: In function `build_nbayes_classifier(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
/home/courtneymaroney/opencv/samples/cpp/letter_recog.cpp:467: undefined reference to `cv::ml::NormalBayesClassifier::create()'
/tmp/ccUbgW02.o: In function `build_svm_classifier(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
/home/courtneymaroney/opencv/samples/cpp/letter_recog.cpp:504: undefined reference to `cv::ml::SVM::create()'
/tmp/ccUbgW02.o: In function `main':
/home/courtneymaroney/opencv/samples/cpp/letter_recog.cpp:524: undefined reference to `cv::CommandLineParser::CommandLineParser(int, char const* const*, cv::String const&)'
/home/courtneymaroney/opencv/samples/cpp/letter_recog.cpp:526: undefined reference to `cv::CommandLineParser::has(cv::String const&) const'
/home/courtneymaroney/opencv/samples/cpp/letter_recog.cpp:528: undefined reference to `cv::CommandLineParser::has(cv::String const&) const'
/home/courtneymaroney/opencv/samples/cpp/letter_recog.cpp:530: undefined reference to `cv::CommandLineParser::has(cv::String const&) const'
/home/courtneymaroney/opencv/samples/cpp/letter_recog.cpp:532: undefined reference to `cv::CommandLineParser::has(cv::String const&) const'
/home/courtneymaroney/opencv/samples/cpp/letter_recog.cpp:534: undefined reference to `cv::CommandLineParser::has(cv::String const&) const'
/tmp/ccUbgW02.o:/home/courtneymaroney/opencv/samples/cpp/letter_recog.cpp:536: more undefined references to `cv::CommandLineParser::has(cv::String const&) const' follow
/tmp/ccUbgW02.o: In function `main':
/home/courtneymaroney/opencv/samples/cpp/letter_recog.cpp:557: undefined reference to `cv::CommandLineParser::~CommandLineParser()'
/home/courtneymaroney/opencv/samples/cpp/letter_recog.cpp:524: undefined reference to `cv::CommandLineParser::~CommandLineParser()'
/tmp/ccUbgW02.o: In function `cv::String::String(char const*)':
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cvstd.hpp:618: undefined reference to `cv::String::allocate(unsigned long)'
/tmp/ccUbgW02.o: In function `cv::String::~String()':
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cvstd.hpp:660: undefined reference to `cv::String::deallocate()'
/tmp/ccUbgW02.o: In function `cv::Mat::Mat(int, int, int, void*, unsigned long)':
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp:413: undefined reference to `cv::error(int, cv::String const&, char const*, char const*, int)'
/tmp/ccUbgW02.o: In function `cv::Mat::~Mat()':
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp:556: undefined reference to `cv::fastFree(void*)'
/tmp/ccUbgW02.o: In function `cv::Mat::row(int) const':
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp:591: undefined reference to `cv::Mat::Mat(cv::Mat const&, cv::Range const&, cv::Range const&)'
/tmp/ccUbgW02.o: In function `cv::Mat::rowRange(int, int) const':
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp:603: undefined reference to `cv::Mat::Mat(cv::Mat const&, cv::Range const&, cv::Range const&)'
/tmp/ccUbgW02.o: In function `cv::Mat::colRange(int, int) const':
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp:615: undefined reference to `cv::Mat::Mat(cv::Mat const&, cv::Range const&, cv::Range const&)'
/tmp/ccUbgW02.o: In function `cv::Mat::create(int, int, int)':
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp:648: undefined reference to `cv::Mat::create(int, int const*, int)'
/tmp/ccUbgW02.o: In function `cv::Mat::release()':
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp:667: undefined reference to `cv::Mat::deallocate()'
/tmp/ccUbgW02.o: In function `cv::FileStorage::getFirstTopLevelNode() const':
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/persistence.hpp:1167: undefined reference to `cv::FileStorage::root(int) const'
/tmp/ccUbgW02.o: In function `cv::FileNode::begin() const':
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/persistence.hpp:1184: undefined reference to `cv::FileNodeIterator::FileNodeIterator(CvFileStorage const*, CvFileNode const*, unsigned long)'
/tmp/ccUbgW02.o: In function `cv::FileNode::end() const':
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/persistence.hpp:1185: undefined reference to `cv::FileNode::size() const'
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/persistence.hpp:1185: undefined reference to `cv::FileNodeIterator::FileNodeIterator(CvFileStorage const*, CvFileNode const*, unsigned long)'
/tmp/ccUbgW02.o: In function `cv::String::String(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cvstd.inl.hpp:81: undefined reference to `cv::String::allocate(unsigned long)'
/tmp/ccUbgW02.o: In function `cv::String cv::CommandLineParser::get<cv::String>(cv::String const&, bool) const':
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/utility.hpp:682: undefined reference to `cv::CommandLineParser::getByName(cv::String const&, bool, int, void*) const'
/tmp/ccUbgW02.o: In function `cv::Mat::Mat<int>(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&, bool)':
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp:469: undefined reference to `cv::Mat::copyTo(cv::_OutputArray const&) const'
/tmp/ccUbgW02.o: In function `cv::Mat::Mat<double>(std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > const&, bool)':
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp:469: undefined reference to `cv::Mat::copyTo(cv::_OutputArray const&) const'
/tmp/ccUbgW02.o: In function `cv::Ptr<cv::ml::RTrees> cv::Algorithm::load<cv::ml::RTrees>(cv::String const&, cv::String const&)':
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core.hpp:2972: undefined reference to `cv::FileStorage::FileStorage(cv::String const&, int, cv::String const&)'
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core.hpp:2973: undefined reference to `cv::FileStorage::operator[](cv::String const&) const'
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core.hpp:2974: undefined reference to `cv::ml::RTrees::create()'
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core.hpp:2972: undefined reference to `cv::FileStorage::~FileStorage()'
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core.hpp:2972: undefined reference to `cv::FileStorage::~FileStorage()'
/tmp/ccUbgW02.o: In function `cv::Ptr<cv::ml::Boost> cv::Algorithm::load<cv::ml::Boost>(cv::String const&, cv::String const&)':
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core.hpp:2972: undefined reference to `cv::FileStorage::FileStorage(cv::String const&, int, cv::String const&)'
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core.hpp:2973: undefined reference to `cv::FileStorage::operator[](cv::String const&) const'
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core.hpp:2974: undefined reference to `cv::ml::Boost::create()'
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core.hpp:2972: undefined reference to `cv::FileStorage::~FileStorage()'
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core.hpp:2972: undefined reference to `cv::FileStorage::~FileStorage()'
/tmp/ccUbgW02.o: In function `cv::Ptr<cv::ml::ANN_MLP> cv::Algorithm::load<cv::ml::ANN_MLP>(cv::String const&, cv::String const&)':
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core.hpp:2972: undefined reference to `cv::FileStorage::FileStorage(cv::String const&, int, cv::String const&)'
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core.hpp:2973: undefined reference to `cv::FileStorage::operator[](cv::String const&) const'
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core.hpp:2974: undefined reference to `cv::ml::ANN_MLP::create()'
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core.hpp:2972: undefined reference to `cv::FileStorage::~FileStorage()'
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core.hpp:2972: undefined reference to `cv::FileStorage::~FileStorage()'
/tmp/ccUbgW02.o: In function `cv::Ptr<cv::ml::SVM> cv::Algorithm::load<cv::ml::SVM>(cv::String const&, cv::String const&)':
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core.hpp:2972: undefined reference to `cv::FileStorage::FileStorage(cv::String const&, int, cv::String const&)'
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core.hpp:2973: undefined reference to `cv::FileStorage::operator[](cv::String const&) const'
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core.hpp:2974: undefined reference to `cv::ml::SVM::create()'
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core.hpp:2972: undefined reference to `cv::FileStorage::~FileStorage()'
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core.hpp:2972: undefined reference to `cv::FileStorage::~FileStorage()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Compilation failed.
```

I am using an IDE called "Geany" for Ubuntu 16.04.

The compile/build commands for granny are as follows:
Compile:
g++ -std=c++14 -Wall -c "%f"
Build:
g++ -g -std=c++14 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -lpthread  -o "%e"  "%f"

I was looking on the internet for possible solutions. It seems like some people have this problem but no one has found a solution to it yet, or at least no one has shared one for this.

Output of echo $(pkg-config --libs opencv) [I formatted it to make it more readable]:

```
echo $(pkg-config --libs opencv)

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_calib3d.so

 -lopencv_calib3d

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_contrib.so

 -lopencv_contrib 

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_core.so 

-lopencv_core

 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_features2d.so 

-lopencv_features2d 

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_flann.so

 -lopencv_flann

 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_gpu.so 

-lopencv_gpu 

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so

 -lopencv_highgui

 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_imgproc.so 

-lopencv_imgproc 

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_legacy.so

 -lopencv_legacy 

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_ml.so

 -lopencv_ml 

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_objdetect.so

 -lopencv_objdetect 

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_ocl.so

-lopencv_ocl 

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_photo.so

 -lopencv_photo 

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_stitching.so 

-lopencv_stitching 

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_superres.so 

-lopencv_superres

 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_ts.so 

-lopencv_ts 

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_video.so

 -lopencv_video

 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopencv_videostab.so

 -lopencv_videostab
```

Comment: You've got to link with the OpenCV libraries you're using.

Comment: I tried that. It for rid of some of the issues, but it says that imgcodecs cannot be found. Also is there a quicker way or command line to do it easily each time?

Comment: "no one has found a solution" -- Knowing how to compile and link your code is such a fundamental skill, that I can't imagine anyone competent feeling the need to write a separate article for every single piece of code lying around on the net. You just need to understand the general principles, and how to apply them. | Which version of OpenCV are you using? The modules available in the 2.4 branch are different from those in the 3.x branch. | Regarding the command line question -- I prefer to use CMake. I suggest reading up on what it is and how to use it.

Comment: To elaborate a bit on the last part, to compile non-trivial code, you usually use some other program to drive the compilation, and feed it with some description of what you want to build and how. On unix-like systems, it's often a program called "make" (for simple things you could just write a shell script). However, it's a bit of a pain to write makefiles, so there is a level of abstraction above that -- CMake is such a case. It allows you to describe things in a more general way, and then generates the files necessary to build the code with a particular toolkit.

Comment: It's OpenCV 3.0

Comment: OK, if it's 3.0 then imgcodecs module should be available (that is, unless it was a "world" build in which case there's just one lib containing everything).

Comment: I know it /should/ be there, and in my folder it says it's there, but when I try to link to it, it says it's not found

Comment: Do you happen to have some other version of OpenCV installed on your system? Check apt. That looks like 2.4.x installed as a standard package. You said you moved the headers to `/usr/local/...` so I'd expect to see the binaries somwhere there as well, not in `/usr/lib`.

Comment: It is in local, but I am not sure why it is not showing what is in local. opencv is not even _in_ local. I am not sure why it's saying that.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand how you installed `opencv` on your system, and if you really copied manually the headers in your system path then probably I don't want to know. Also I'm allergic to IDE, so let's use the more friendly terminal.

Usually the best option is by installing the one in your repository. In your case (from the tags of your question it appears an ubuntu 16.10):

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libopencv-dev
```

this will fix the `pkg-config` files that will help you in compilation. (**Disclaimer** the presence of manually copied headers may disturb the installation process. I suggest you to remove them prior to issue these two commands, if you put them in `/usr/include`)

Now for the compilation of `letter_recog.cpp` it is sufficient to call the compiler in this way:

```
g++ $(pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv) letter_recog.cpp -o letter_recog
```

If you want you may also add your flags (`-Wall -pedantic` etc etc), but I suggest you to check what `pkg-config` does with:

```
echo $(pkg-config --cflags opencv)
echo $(pkg-config --libs opencv)
```

the second in particular is what you apparently missed (the libraries to link against).

Finally, for fixing in Geany I suspect you have to put somewhere something like:

```
g++ -std=c++14 -Wall $(pkg-config --cflags opencv) -c "%f"
```

and

```
g++ -g -std=c++14 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -lpthread $(pkg-config --libs opencv) -o "%e" "%f"
```

but this solution is questionable (like the `-lpthread` instead of `-pthread`; and also you don't need them for that code).

**Long story short**: Listen  to the first comment of Dan Mašek: he is right.

(sorry for the typos it is very late in my fuse)

Comment: Thanks. Will try it and then get back to you guys.

Comment: I'll be AFK for the next few hours.

Comment: I tried this and it did not work at all. I am still getting the same errors. It appears that basically for anything related to opencv (cv::) it has an error.

Comment: @CourtneyMaroney In your question you mention moving include files. What did you do with the binaries? Try to seach for them, maybe you don't have the linker search path set correctly?

Comment: What is the output of `echo $(pkg-config --libs opencv)`?

Comment: It's too long, so I will edit my main post and put it there.

Comment: Mh from the output it is clear that there is something wrong with your installation. It should print out only a sequence of `-lopencv...` where `...` is the name of the particular opencv element. Please describe carefully everything you have done to install opencv.

Comment: I used this website: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html What should I use instead? What is the correct installation of opencv on linux?

Comment: @Matteo Ragni, thanks, your comment was very helpful. Whole thing was screwed up, so I found a better installation guide, reinstalled it, and now it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed: Reinstalled it using this guide:

https://medium.com/@debugvn/installing-opencv-3-3-0-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts-7db376f93961

Didn't work with only putting `g++ $(pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv) letter_recog.cpp -o letter_recog` so I had to add some flags (-lopencv_name_of_library)

I'm a bit of a noob with makefiles. Once I find a way to substitute filenames for variables with Makefiles, I will give a custom makefile here (as an edit) to compile/build the projects, but so far, since I am using an IDE called **Geany**, I am using the ***build*** command (for all of the projects, doesn't matter which one)

```
g++ $(pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv) %f -o %e -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_superres -lopencv_videostab -lopencv_photo -lopencv_aruco -lopencv_bgsegm -lopencv_bioinspired -lopencv_ccalib -lopencv_dpm -lopencv_face -lopencv_freetype -lopencv_fuzzy -lopencv_img_hash -lopencv_line_descriptor -lopencv_optflow -lopencv_reg -lopencv_rgbd -lopencv_saliency -lopencv_stereo -lopencv_structured_light -lopencv_phase_unwrapping -lopencv_surface_matching -lopencv_tracking -lopencv_datasets -lopencv_text -lopencv_dnn -lopencv_plot -lopencv_ml -lopencv_xfeatures2d -lopencv_shape -lopencv_video -lopencv_ximgproc -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_flann -lopencv_xobjdetect -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_xphoto -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_core
```

Thanks guys for the help. Most helpful comment was the one suggesting that I installed it incorrectly. Hope my findings help other people. (Trust me, it was hell, after trying a different installation guide, tried to install an nvidia driver and it corrupted my whole OS, so I had to uninstall that OS, reinstall the OS with a clean slate, and started over (lost all my files in the process))

Hope you guys don't have to go through the trouble I did. It was hell, but I think opencv is pretty worth it.